# $X$ be a path connected space , then any continuous map on $X$ induces the identity map on $0$-th singular homology group of $X$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a path connected space , $f:X \to X$ be any continuous map ; then is the induced map between $0$-th singular homology groups of $X$ , $H_0(f) : H_0(X) \to H_0(X)$ identity ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since there exists a path $c_x$ between $x$ and $f(x)$ so they are homologous since the boundary of $c_x$ is is $[x]-[f(x)]$ or $[f(x)]-[x].$